# backbone event not firing with small css change - add css float to img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js, marionette

--Solved , see bottom of OP

The only change was adding the css block below to float an image tag with text on the same line.

Error - after the css change, jquery sees the 'click' event on the image (class=usrgrp) but backbone does not receive any call to "triggerEvents" function. I've observed this in debug.

-- code before works fine

```
<div class="pichdr">
    <a href="#" class="usrgrp">
    <img src="../../../../../Content/images/group-sm.png"   width="40" height="40">
    </a>
<label class="parent-role"> 
    <%= name %></label>
</div>
<ul id="todo-list"></ul>

...
//In marionette composite view.. 

    events : {
          "click .usrgrp" : "roleRelation"
    },

    roleRelation : function(e) {
        console.log("RoleUsrLst.getrole CLIK"); //not appearing with new css
        vent.trigger('roleuserlist:getrole', this.model);
    }
```

add the following to css and the click no longer fires in backbone ie "triggerEvent()" no longer getting called in backbone debug although jquery is getting the event from DOM.

```
.usrgrp  {

    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    float: left;

}
```

The css floats the image ok, aligning it with text on the same line.

But the css change breaks the click event somehow.

Note: before resorting to css.float i tried the following html on the image tag

style="vertical-align:middle"

and it did not work for some reason.

--Solved by changed css below

on the img tag :  style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;"

and on the label , in css , added following:

display: inline-block;
text-align: left;

Comment: Have you tried actually applying the CSS to the img, not the wrapping anchor tag? 

.usrgrp > img

Comment: yes already tried " .usrgrp > img" . result NG

Comment: thanks . i will try to get to it on fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your events like this :

```
events : {
      "click .usrgrp img" : "roleRelation"
}
```

Comment: ill try this..i got it fixed by twiddling the css as noted in EDIT to OP

Comment: nope . did not work . Backbone was just not getting events from jQry??